# RTL on MuiTextField goes wrong using Special Charcters

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm currently working on a project using Mui, I have successfully implemented RTL using Mui guide.
I'm facing an annoying issue where special characters on MuiTextField are aligned to the Left and not to the right.

When typing secretpassword123! into a TextField the the '!' character goes to the left.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/er7H0.png)

```
      <TextField
        error={Boolean(formik.touched.password && formik.errors.password)}
        fullWidth
        helperText={formik.touched.password && formik.errors.password}
        label={t("password")}
        margin="dense"
        name="password"
        onBlur={formik.handleBlur && handlePasswordFieldBlur}
        onFocus={handlePasswordFieldFocus}
        onChange={formik.handleChange}
        type={isPasswordVisible ? "text" : "password"}
        value={formik.values.password}
        InputProps={{
          endAdornment: (
            <InputAdornment position="end">
              <IconButton onClick={handleVisibilityIconClick}>
                {isPasswordVisible ? <Visibility /> : <VisibilityOff />}
              </IconButton>
            </InputAdornment>
          ),
        }}
      />
```

I have noticed many people faced the same issue but the solutions were not good for my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is standard behavior with RTL. Here is the same password typed into google's IL website [image: google's] . It's not a bug but a feature and it's what RTL users are used to in all their other apps/websites when typing latin text.

To override just one TextField per [docs](https://mui.com/guides/right-to-left/#opting-out-of-rtl-transformation), you can do the following:

```js
import { styled } from '@mui/material';

const LtrInput = styled("input")`
  /* @noflip */
  direction: ltr;
`;

<TextField
  InputProps={{ inputComponent: LtrInput }}
  label={"Test"}
  sx={{ "& .MuiInputBase-input": { textAlign: "end" } }}
/>
```

Comment: Yea well, I want to override the standard, as it may confuse users.

Comment: It won't confuse RTL users as any RTL user expects text in an RTL field to be, well, RTL – meaning right to left. So naturally, typing will be in that direction and hence it's at the very left as intended. That's the way the password field is on every Israeli bank website where the user has to fill out the password field (and the password is likely a hebrew phrase rather than a latin one).

If you want to override just that field, (again, that would be weird for a native RTL user), go right ahead and override just that component))

Comment: I've added an example of how to override just one TextField to my answer. Hope that helps.

Comment: using your example I solved the issue, Thanks!
If you can i would realy like to understand how does the & thing works.
sx={{ "& .MuiInputBase-input": { textAlign: "end" } }}

Comment: Here are the [docs](https://mui.com/customization/how-to-customize/#overriding-nested-component-styles) for overriding nested component styles :)

Answer (score 0):

using @Sam A. advice
I have added to the TextField the props

```js
    dir: "ltr",
    sx: { "& .MuiInputBase-input": { textAlign: "end" } }
```

and it solved the issue :)

FullCode

```js
      <TextField
        error={Boolean(formik.touched.password && formik.errors.password)}
        fullWidth
        helperText={formik.touched.password && formik.errors.password}
        label={t("password")}
        margin="dense"
        name="password"
        onBlur={formik.handleBlur && handlePasswordFieldBlur}
        onFocus={handlePasswordFieldFocus}
        onChange={formik.handleChange}
        type={isPasswordVisible ? "text" : "password"}
        value={formik.values.password}
        InputProps={{
          startAdornment: (
            <InputAdornment position="start">
              <IconButton onClick={handleVisibilityIconClick}>
                {isPasswordVisible ? <Visibility /> : <VisibilityOff />}
              </IconButton>
            </InputAdornment>
          ),
          dir: "ltr",
          sx: { "& .MuiInputBase-input": { textAlign: "end" } },
        }}
      />
```

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ROVw.png)